# How do I implement 'import ... as' using the __import__() function?

Tags: python, import, module

I would like to 'import ... as' dynamically.

I know that importing in Python calls `__import__()` in the background, e.g.:

```
import foo
```

is equivalent to

```
foo = __import__('foo', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

How does `import foo as bar` call `__import__()`?

Comment: It just assigns the result to `bar`.  So just do `bar = __import__(whatever)`.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- well, that's easy, isn't it?  Might as well post it as an answer and be done with it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just assigns the result to bar. So just do `bar = __import__(whatever)`.